# Mongoose automatically change the type of the value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

In **mongoose.model**, I have chosen the type of `name` to be a `string` and the type of `age` to be a `number`, but when I enter a number as the value of name, I don't get an error and the same thing happens when I use something like `'18'` as the value of age.

Here is the code:

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', {
  name: { type: String },
  age: { type: Number }
});

const me = new User({
  name: 12,
  age: '18'
});

me.save().then(() => console.log(me)).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: @Naren this is not a duplicate, the indicated post is about validation, but the question here is about casting, which takes place before validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mongoose` casts the values to the corresponding type, if it fails a `CastError` is thrown, from the [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#cast-errors):

> Before running validators, Mongoose attempts to coerce values to the
> correct type. This process is called casting the document. If casting
> fails for a given path, the `error.errors` object will contain a `CastError` object.

You can try this by given `age` the value `'aa'` for example.

If you want to override this behavior you can use one of the following options:

1. Disable casting globally: `mongoose.Number.cast(false)`
2. Disable casting just for a given path:

```
age: {
  type: Number, 
  cast: false // Disable casting just for this path
},
```

3. Use a custom function:

```
age: {
    type: Number,
    cast: v => { return typeof v === 'number' && !isNaN(v) ? Number(v) : v; } // Override casting just for this path
  }
```

Comment: is there a way to disable this and make it only respond to the chosen type?